# Locale messages from diffrent apps resolving in the template

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Django apps can have own message files, locates in their directories. And, suppose, i have an 2 diffrent apps, that is differently translate similar word. It is clear that when gettext used inside the app it will be translated by app's own message file.
How can i predict which translation will be selected when i'm using {%trans%} tag in the template? Is there order, or priority how django resolves this while rendering template?

Answer (score 0):

If it is application you develop, the best approach to ensure correct translation is being used is by [specifying context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) in template or code. This is fully supported as of Django 1.4.